# How to fix [object Object] and render from a has many relationship in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, oop, serialization

I'm working a show page with Ajax where I have an educational course rendered with the course instructor but Im getting [object Object] when trying to set the students of that particular course. I would like to render all the students for the course.

I tried adding students as an attribute to the course serializer.

```
class CourseSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :instructor, :students


    has_many :ratings
    has_many :students, through: :ratings
end
```

This is my click event.

```
$(document).on('click','.show_link',function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $('.ajaxStyling').html('')
  let id = $(this).attr('data-id')
  fetch(`/courses/${id}.json`)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(course => {
    let newCourse = new Course(course)
    let courseHtml = newCourse.formatShow()
    $('.ajaxStyling').append(courseHtml)
  })
})
```

Constructor function.

```
function Course(course) {
  this.id = course.id
  this.name = course.name
  this.instructor = course.instructor
  this.students = course.students
}
```

Prototype function.

```
Course.prototype.formatShow = function () {
  let courseHtml = `
  <a href="/courses/${this.id}" data-id="${this.id}"><h3 class="showText">${this.name} by ${this.instructor}</h3></a>
  ${this.students}.forEach(function(student) {
    return "<p>" + student.first_name + "</p>"
  })
  `
  return courseHtml
}
```

But Im getting the following error in page.

This renders as a link which works as intended --> Adobe Analytics 201 by Adam Greco

But the following is not right. Code rendered in page below the link above-->

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object].forEach(function(student) { 
return "" + student.first_name + "" })
```

This is the data in my network request.

```
{id: 6, name: "Adobe Analytics 201", instructor: "Adam Greco",…}
id: 6
instructor: "Adam Greco"
name: "Adobe Analytics 201"
ratings: [{id: 29, rating: 2, course_id: 6, student_id: 11, created_at: "2019-05-23T00:54:22.813Z",…},…]
students: [{id: 11, first_name: "Stefan", last_name: "Candelaria"}]
0: {id: 11, first_name: "Stefan", last_name: "Candelaria"}
1: {id: 12, first_name: "Robby", last_name: "Pasurin"}
2: {id: 10, first_name: "Rafa", last_name: "Lopez"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try doing everything inside the template literal string. Also `forEach` doesn't do anything with `return`

Try something like:

```
Course.prototype.formatShow = function() {
  let courseHtml = `
  <a href="/courses/${this.id}" data-id="${this.id}"><h3 class="showText">${this.name} by ${this.instructor}</h3></a> `;

  courseHtml += this.students.map(function(student) {
    return `<p>${student.first_name}</p>`;
  }).join('');


  return courseHtml
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...specially for the return part ; )